# How to remove [unknown page] in Sitecore analytics

Tags: xdb, sitecore-client

I would like to know how to remove the `[unknown page]` part in the Sitecore
analytics dashboard?
I am pretty much sure that they are internal api calls and google tracking etc, it´s displaying unwanted data in the dashboard.

[image: unknown page image sitecore analytics]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

It does not appear that there is any way to disable this page from the Report Builder which is used to populate this page. I'll attempt to walk this through:

The `Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.ReportingService` creates a new object called `LiveReportResponseBuilder()` in the `RunQuery()` method.

```
public ReportResponse RunQuery(ReportQuery reportQuery)
{
  IReportQueryData data = reportQuery.GetData();
  CachingPolicy cachingPolicy = new CachingPolicy()
  {
    ExpirationPeriod = reportQuery.RequestType.GetServerSideExpiration()
  };
  IEnumerable<ReportRow> reportData = this.reportDataService.ExecuteQuery(data, cachingPolicy);
  return new LiveReportResponseBuilder(this.dimensionDefinitionService, this.aggregationSegmentReader, this.segmentReader, data, reportData).GetReportResponse();
}
```

The `LiveReportResponseBuilder` class has a private method called `GetDimensionKeyMap()`.  In this method, the Dimension Key trying to be resolved cannot be transformed for the given language, and thus a mapping is added to the response of "Unknown".

```
    if (key1.IsOther())
    {
      dimensionKeyMap.Mapping.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key1, "Other"));
    }
    else
    {
      string key2 = keyStringReplacer.Replace(key1);
      try
      {
        string str = transformer.Transform(key1, language);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && !key1.Equals(str))
          dimensionKeyMap.Mapping.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key2, str));
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
          dimensionKeyMap.Mapping.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key2, Translate.Text(transformer.UnknownLabel)));
          dimensionKeyMap.FailedMappings.Add(key1);
        }
      }
      catch (InvalidTypeMappingException ex)
      {
        dimensionKeyMap.Mapping.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key2, Translate.Text(transformer.UnknownLabel)));
        dimensionKeyMap.FailedMappings.Add(key1);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        ApiContainer.GetLogger().Error(string.Format("Transformer '{0}' failed for key '{1}'. Message: {2}. Details: {3}", (object) transformer.GetType().FullName, (object) key1, (object) ex.Message, (object) ex.StackTrace));
        dimensionKeyMap.Mapping.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key2, Translate.Text(transformer.UnknownLabel)));
        dimensionKeyMap.FailedMappings.Add(key1);
      }
    }
```

### Why is this happening?

If I am reading this correctly, there is an Analytics Dimension Key that is either not defined correctly or has no associated value mapping.  Dimensions are stored in Sitecore in `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Experience Analytics/Dimensions`.

All Interactions in Sitecore that are tracked to a dimension are stored in Mongo by GUID ID.  If for some reason, there are interactions in Mongo that do not relate to a Dimension ID in Sitecore, then this can cause an "Unknown Page" mapping.

This can happen if a dimension is removed from Sitecore.  This is also more noticeable if a dimension is removed and then the Reporting DB is rebuilt.

This can also occur if there is a mismatch between what is stored as dimensions in the Sitecore Config, The Sitecore Master DB, and the Reporting DB.

Normally, the Sitecore Log on the Processing Role server will show errors about missing dimensions that can provide you some insight on the dimension id is missing.

It could be as simple as restoring the appropriate dimension information and rebuilding the Reporting Database in order to get rid of the "Unknown Page"

Otherwise, there is no other way to exclude Unknown Pages from Sitecore Analytics.