# What Roles we need to assign for an user to access Experience Analytics without any issues?

Tags: experience-analytics

We have created a user and assigned the below 2 roles

1. Sitecore\Analytics Reporting
2. Sitecore\Developer

Please check the below screenshot of the user profile after assigning above 2 roles.

[image: Roles assigned to the newly created user]

We logged-in with the newly created user and tried to access below page.

```
Experience Analytics > Behavior > Pages
```

In the above page, all Entry and Exit pages are getting displayed as `[unknown page]`. Please check the below screenshot for the reference.

[image: Screenshot reference for the issue]

The same report is displaying fine for Admin users. Do we need to assign any other roles / permissions to display actual page name instead of all `[unknown page]`?

Comment: Can you try to add another role "Analytics Management Reporting"? What item permissions this role has? Does it have access to pages that are being reporting? Just guessing as I am not next to computer to check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have the role `Analytics Management Reporting` added to the user.

> Then Analytics Management Reporting Role gives the user access to view
>   the management reports for optimization efforts. This role is
>   typically given to users working with optimization, who wants to view
>   management reports for the optimization efforts.
>
> More info at [Sitecore Security Roles](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles)

When you finish adding the role, you need to logout and also try to clear the Sitecore Cache via the `cache.aspx` page. I've seen that the results are still in the cache even after logout.

Moreover, while testing I have seen the following behavior:

1. The user should have access to the item: read and write.
2. Upon selection of the site from the dropdown at the top right corner, I have seen that the item are displayed properly. So, try to filter to the site you want to check.
3. Even as an Administrator, I was able to see that some entries were still as `Unknown Page`. My guest is because those are APIs which do not map to any items.

Furthermore, from the following SSE [answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9598/how-to-remove-unknown-page-in-sitecore-analytics?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) by Pete Navarra, the unknown page may be due to Analytics Dimension Key is either not defined correctly or has no associated value mapping. All Interactions in Sitecore that are tracked to a dimension are stored in Mongo by GUID ID. If for some reason, there are interactions in Mongo that do not relate to a Dimension ID in Sitecore, then this can cause an "Unknown Page" mapping.

Comment: Thank you very much @hishaam-namooya. This worked fine with my account. Have to check other accounts.